# Using awk, how can I save records to another file if the condition below doesn't meet?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

How can I save records to another file if the condition below doesn't meet. I only have "if" below, i do not know where to put else condition.

```
 awk '                                       
 NF {                                        
 data  = substr ($0, 1, 14)    
 data2 = substr ($0, 1, 1)         
 count = gsub (/0/, "", data)               
  }   

 {if (count<=11 || data2!=5) print }' $FILES > ${DST}/${FILES}
```

Comment: `{if (count<=11 || data2!=5) {print} else {} }`

Comment: Where can I put another destination? For instance, if if (count<=11 || data2!=5 then save to ${DST}/${FILES} else save to ${DST_B}/${FILES}.

Comment: you need to put them in side if block. `{if (count<=11 || data2!=5) print > ${DST}/${FILES} }' $FILES` .

Answer (score 2):

You can do the redirection inside `awk` script. Call your `bash` variables from `awk` by using the `-v` construct. `FILENAME` is `awk` built-in variable that holds the name of the file which it will receive from `${FILES}` variable during run-time.

```
awk -v dst="${DST}" -v dstb="${DST_B}" '                                       
NF {                                        
    data  = substr ($0, 1, 14)    
    data2 = substr ($0, 1, 1)         
    count = gsub (/0/, "", data)               
    if (count<=11 || data2!=5) {
        print > ( dst "/" FILENAME )
    }
    else {
        print > ( dstb "/" FILENAME )
    }
}' $FILES
```

Comment: what is gsub, and print > @jaypal and why "in beginning" when commenting here mentioning someone with @ deletes mention

Comment: @josifoski `gsub` is an `awk` built-in function that does global substitution. `print >` allows you to perform re-direction inside `awk` script. `@` is used if you want to re-direct to your comment to someone who has left a comment. Since there weren't any it removes it. `:)`